# Show NSSearchFields clear button at all times

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nssearchfield

I want to use the clear `✖️` button of an `NSSearchField` to close a search pane. Therefore I have manually set the action and target of the clear button cell. Now the button only appears when the search field has text in it and I can't find a way to override this behavior.

Is it possible to show the clear button at all times, wether there is text or not?

Comment: out of curiosity, what do you want to happen when the clear button is pressed when there is no text in the field?

Comment: The search pane would be collapsed/closed.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I have the same use case